# SAS Macro variables not resolving in remote server

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Hello I am having some trouble with a macro that tries to access a remote server and download data.  The macro code is bold below, followed by the log data.  main issue is that the data passed to the macro is not resolved in calls on the remote server but are if a put statement is executed.

I assume that there is something about the local nature of the data stored in the macros that is not getting passed to the remote server and the %put is executed locally, but the remotely executed upload does not recognize &sdb.

Thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated.

```
%macro getcrspprices( dvar,rl, rh, mvar, sdb, odb, cdb); 
%let wrds=wrds.wharton.upenn.edu 4016; 
options comamid=TCP remote=WRDS; 
signon username= %%%% password="%%%%" ; 
rsubmit; 
libname crsp '/wrds/crsp/sasdata/a_stock'; 
%put &sdb; 
proc upload data=&sdb out=dta; 
run; *upload file from my computer;
```

LOG data is italics below

The MPRINT output for the later portion:

```
MPRINT(GETCRSPPRICES):  ; libname crsp '/wrds/crsp/sasdata/a_stock';
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SDB resolves to work.spinnerslist
work.spinnerslist
MPRINT(GETCRSPPRICES):   proc upload data=&sdb out=dta;
MPRINT(GETCRSPPRICES):   run;
```

Then the error is centered around the upload statement:

```
proc upload data=&sdb out=dta;
                  -
                  22
                  200
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference SDB not resolved.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name,
          a quoted string.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer!.  to get your locally defined macro variables on the remote server use %syslput.  More here: http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts697.pdf

Hope this helps future frustrations

Comment: In this case, it's the remote macro variable which needs copying to the local session - use %SYSRPUT in the remote session to set a local macro variable, e.g. `%SYSRPUT SDB = &SDB`